# Masking ampersands in output of a sysget call

Tags: sas

To get the file name of the current SAS program we can write

```
%put %sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH);
```

I am so unfortunate that someone once created a directory that included an ampersand in the path (yikes!). Let us create an example folder `C:\temp&other` and store our `test.sas` program here in that folder.

Now, my question is:

### Is it possible to mask the output of `%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)` to avoid SAS trying to resolve a macro variable `&other`?

The easy solution would be to change the path name but things are unfortunately not always easy and I am not allowed to change the folder name.

---

My attempts: 
None of the `nr` functions I have tried help me, since they mask both `%` and `&`. I have tried the following (indented line is the SAS log output). Note that `%NRQUOTE` outputs the same as the "naked" call.

```
%put %sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH); 
    /* WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OTHER not resolved. */
    /* C:\temp&other\test.sas */

%put %nrstr(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH));
    /* %nrstr(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH)) */

%put %nrquote(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH));
    /* WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OTHER not resolved. */
    /* C:\temp&other\test.sas */

%put %superq(%sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH));
    /* WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OTHER not resolved.*/
    /* ERROR: Invalid symbolic variable name C\TEST&OTHER\TEST.SAS. */
```

Comment: I don't think you can. I think you'll have to partially or fully hard code the directory part and enclose it with single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To eliminate the warning about the undefined macro variable (and worse the possibility of it actually finding and using an existing macro variable) you will need to use the SAS function SYSGET() instead of the macro function %SYSGET().

If you cannot run SAS code then you can use the macro function %QSYSFUNC() to run the SAS function and quote the returned value.

```
%put %qsysfunc(sysget(SAS_EXECFILEPATH));
```

If might even be useful to define a macro "function" %qsysget() in your personal autocall library. Perhaps something like this:

```
%macro qsysget(name);
  %if -1=%sysfunc(envlen(&name)) %then %put WARNING: Environment variable "&name" not found.;
  %else %qsysfunc(sysget(&name));
%mend;
```

Comment: Perfect! Made it clear to me why the other answer also works - using the SAS function instead of the macro function of `sysget`. Also, smart trick you use to check if a macro variable exists :)

Answer (score 5):

Use a `data _null_` step with `call symputx` to create a macro variable that holds the value of `sas_execfilepath`. You can then resolve it with `%superq()`.

```
data _null_;
    call symputx('sas_execfilepath', sysget('sas_execfilepath'));
run;

%put %superq(sas_execfilepath);
```

Log output:

```
C:\temp&other\test.sas
```